# gnome-screenshot is not working and fails 90% of the time

Tags: screenshot, gnome-screenshot

When using keyboard shortcuts, or typing `gnome-screenshot` into terminal, it only works about 10% of the time. When using `-a` to select the area, the area selector cursor + appears, but after selecting an area, no file is created, no shutter sound goes off. If I press UP in terminal to repeat the command and keep selecting screen areas, about one time in ten, I get the shutter sound, and the screenshot is saved under ~/Pictures.

Using `-c` to save to clipboard, or specifying a `--file` also does not help.

When it fails, terminal behaves just the same as when it works, and I don't see any errors.

I've looked in Logs and don't see anything obvious, but I don't know what to look for either.

I would like to know how to trouble-shoot or fix this issue. Thanks.

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Gnome version: 3.36.8
Windowing System: X11

Comment: Since you are on Xorg, you can try using some other screenshot utility and check if it works. If it works, then you should try to reinstall gnome-screenshot.

Comment: Thanks @Puspam, I tried purging and re-installing gnome-screenshot. This didn't fix it. I've installed flameshot and set my keyboard shorcut command to "flameshot gui" without the "s. This is working really well, and is much more functional for me, so I'll abandon gnome-screenshot for now.